# VSCode run selection in power shell scripts has stopped working

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have been using VSCode for 2 years on a current project, but from yesterday or the day before the run selected rows feature (F8) has stopped working on multiple rows. If I highlight a single row it works but not multiple. Anyone else come across this and is there a workaround please ?

Circled is the command F8

[image]

Its not possible to print the error messages as they are usually to do with the previous row (or line!) not being run.

Comment: Do you mean the `Terminal: Run Selected Text In Active Terminal` command? What's a "_row_"? What _exactly_ do you mean by "_stopped working_"? It does nothing? You get an error message? Give as much detail as you can about what you are observing. Help us help you.

Comment: And where does that run button you've circled in your image come from? An extension? If so, link to that extension's page in the Visual Studio Marketplace and say what version of it you have installed so people can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok @user , if you spent as much time trying to answer the problem as opposed just having a rant, it would be a lot more helpful. Perhaps you are having a bad day, but your tone is way off.  Please delete your comments so someone that may have a helpful answer doesn't have to trawl though this unhelpful noise.

Comment: The first step to answering a question is to understand it, and in questions like these, reproducing it can be an integral part of that process. All I have done is ask clarifying questions. I do not see a problem with my tone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.. So I have found the issue. MS are current updating VSC and one of the updates since Christmas had set a column selection option on. The circled F8 command (run selected lines ) in the original question is standard AFAICT . Here is a screen shot of the selection menu with the column mode option unset. Once this is unselected you can select a series of lines and run just those lines, as before.

[image]

The details of VSCode I am running is

[image]